# Обязательное поле для заполнения (TextView)

Tags: java, android

Как сделать текстовое поле `EditText` обязательным для заполнения? 
Что бы при нажатии на кнопку отправки сообщения, приложение не отправляло пустое сообщение, а проверяла на наличие информации в текстовых полях и при пустом поле кнопка игнорировала нажатие.

Comment: Может вы имеете в виду `EditText`?

Comment: Да, `EditText`. Опечатался..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если в виджете нет текста (включая только пробелы) - заблокировать клик на виджете, если текст есть - разблокировать:

```
    textView.setClickable(!(textView.getText().toString().trim().equals("")));
```

или

```
    int l = textView.getText().toString().trim().length();
    textView.setClickable(l == 0 ? false: true);
```

Вызывать всякий раз когда необходимо проверить контент в виджите на предмет его наличия, либо отсутствия и соответственно позволить обработать клик на виджете или нет.

Подходит для любого виджета, который отрабатывает клики и может содержать текст. В данном случае на примере `TextView`

Comment: Благодарю! Это то, что искал!

Comment: А возможно ли сделать форму с e-mail адресом, которая будет проверять его существование и правильность написание e-mail адреса?

Comment: @BredBear Проверка на валидность ввода конечно возможна, в том числе и на соответствие форме email, только валидация данных это уже совсем другой вопрос и другое решение. Проверка мэйла на существование возможна только фидбэком. То есть отсылаете письмо на этот адрес, а пользователь кликает там на спец.ссылку или вводит полученный код, как это делается при большинстве регистраций на сайтах - и это третий отдельный вопрос, выходящий за рамки первых двух.

Comment: Спасибо, что проинформировали.